# android widget update from service - memory leak?

Tags: android, service, timer, widget

I have a `Service` and I want it to update a widget on the homescreen each second. Therfore the Service listenes to an OnTimerEvent which is send by an `TimeController` each second. The `TimeController` is a singleton holding a handler which runs `mUpdateTimeTask`:

```
public class TimeController {
    private long startTime = -1;
    // ... attributes ... listeners etc
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TimeController.this.notify(new TimerUpdateEvent(this));
            startTime += DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
            mHandler.postAtTime(this, startTime);
        }
    };

    public void startTimer() {
        // if not already running
        if (startTime == -1) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
        }
    };
    // ...
}
```

This all works and the widget get's updated, but in Logcat I see:

```
12-10 22:06:42.825: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17488 objects / 651080 bytes in 112ms
12-10 22:06:44.035: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17479 objects / 650832 bytes in 172ms
12-10 22:06:45.205: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17428 objects / 649744 bytes in 97ms
12-10 22:06:46.315: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17463 objects / 650656 bytes in 86ms
12-10 22:06:47.725: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17793 objects / 663872 bytes in 85ms
12-10 22:06:48.985: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17026 objects / 633944 bytes in 176ms
12-10 22:06:50.145: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17492 objects / 651352 bytes in 89ms
12-10 22:06:51.674: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17435 objects / 650320 bytes in 105ms
12-10 22:06:52.934: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17519 objects / 652584 bytes in 109ms
12-10 22:06:54.234: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17487 objects / 650920 bytes in 90ms
12-10 22:06:55.645: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1738): GC freed 17685 objects / 659448 bytes in 91ms
```

And I don't like what I see... :-)

```
public class MyService extends Service implements TimerUpdateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        timeController = TimeController.getInstance();
        timeController.addListener(this);
        timeController.startTimer();

        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_2x1);
        projectWidget = new ComponentName(this, ProjectWidget.class);

        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onTimerUpdate(TimerUpdateEvent e) {
        updateWidgetViews();
    }

    private void updateWidgetViews() {
        // only update widgets if some exist
        if (appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(projectWidget).length > 0) {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.time, MyDateUtils.timeLeftAsString(project.getInCurrentLevelSince()));

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(projectWidget, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the `remoteViews.setTextViewText(...)` the GC messages do not appear. So how can I update the view without having such a huge memory leaking?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh I forgot: Yes, I know that updates of widgets each second are not recommended, but I really need a update at least every 10 seconds. Anyway I wonder if that GC is a memory leak or if this is caused by the frequently updates?!

Comment: My guess is that something is being allocated in MyDateUtils.timeLeftAsString(); - could you post that function?

Comment: @danh32, if I comment out that and put a fixed string in there, the same allocation occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a Service and I want it to update a widget on the homescreen each second.

Please do not do that. The app widget mechanism is designed for stuff that is updated much less frequently -- say, once every half-hour. You will hammer the user's battery into paste if you do this, and steal CPU time from their foreground app (e.g., cutting frame rate of the game they are playing).

Once you drop the update frequency to something reasonable, please do not have a service whose sole mission in life is to track time. Use `AlarmManager` instead.

> So how can I update the view without having such a huge memory leaking?

By definition, if it is being garbage-collected, it is not a leak. A leak occurs when you allocate memory that is *not* garbage-collected. Hence, you are not leaking memory.

> Oh I forgot: Yes, I know that updates of widgets each second are not recommended, but I really need a update at least every 10 seconds.

Your users really need acceptable performance out of their devices. Your users do not need you consuming all this CPU and RAM. Which means your users need to give you one-star ratings on the Market for being inconsiderate of what *they* need, thinking only of what *you* need, as if you are more important than they are.

At minimum, make this be configurable, so the user actually gets to control whether or not your app deserves what you seek, rather than you dictating terms to them.

Comment: Thanks. Well it would be nice if the widget really count downs in seconds... but ok.. The timer always counts down a week, so I will do it like this: update every hour, until less then 2 hours are left. Then I will update every 10 minutes. In the last hour or last 30 minutes I will do the update every minute and optinally there will be an update in the last minute per x>5 seconds. Seems fair :-)

Comment: @Stuck: Done right, that pattern will be nice for the battery. Again, definitely use `AlarmManager` for that sort of thing -- that way, your code can stay out of RAM when all it does is wait for the next event. If the user toggles on super-frequent updates for last minute in the countdown, then you should probably run a service until the end, using `TimerTask` or something. Just be sure to call `stopSelf()` on the `Service` when you are done with it, so it shuts down and gets out of memory.

Comment: It is very good of you to correctly advise this user that updating a widget every second may not be appreciated by its users, and you have correctly answered the question on the memory leak. I do feel however that most of what you wrote is unnecessary. In this case it is right to suggest the developer consider the effect of a widget that updates every second, it is way over the top however, to surround a single line answer with 4 paragraphs of your personal opinion.

Comment: @Stuck You may be able to combine an AlarmManager with a [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer) view to make it look like the widget is updating every second.